# Consume only commented (/** ..... */ )section of java file thorugh ANTLR 4 and skip the rest

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR and getting familiar with ANTLR 4. How to consume only the commented section (/** ... */) from a java file(or any file) and skip the rest.

I do have the following file "t.txt" :-

### t.txt

```
/**

@Key1("value1")
@Key2("value2")

*/

This is the text that we need to skip. Only wanted to read the above commented section.

//END_OF_FILE
```

AND My grammar file as below:-

MyGrammar.g4

```
grammar MyGrammar;

file : (pair | LINE_COMMENT)* ;

pair : ID VALUE ;

ID  :   '@' ('A'..'Z') (~('('|'\r'|'\n') | '\\)')* ;

VALUE   :  '(' (~('\r'|'\n'))*;

COMMENT : '/**' .*? '*/';

WS : [\t\r\n]+  -> skip;

LINE_COMMENT
     : '#' ~('\r'|'\n')* ('\r'|'\n'|EOF)
     ;
```

I know the COMMENT rule will read the commented section but here i'm stuck that how should skip the rest of the file content and force the antlr to read ID and value from COMMENT content only.

Comment: Thank you Bart, for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lexical modes](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexicalModes) for this. Simply switch to another *mode* when the lexer stumbles upon `"/**"` and ignore everything else.

Note that lexical modes cannot be used in a combined grammar. You will have to define a separate lexer- and parser-grammar.

A small demo:

#### AnnotationLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar AnnotationLexer;

ANNOTATION_START
 : '/**' -> mode(INSIDE), skip
 ;

IGNORE
 : . -> skip
 ;

mode INSIDE;

ID
 : '@' [A-Z] (~[(\r\n] | '\\)')*
 ;

VALUE
 : '(' ~[\r\n]*
 ;

ANNOTATION_END
 : '*/' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE), skip
 ;

IGNORE_INSIDE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

#### file: AnnotationParser.g4

```
parser grammar AnnotationParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=AnnotationLexer;
}

parse
 : pair* EOF
 ;

pair
 : ID VALUE {System.out.println("ID=" + $ID.text + ", VALUE=" + $VALUE.text);}
 ;
```

And now simply use the lexer and parser:

```
String input = "/**\n" +
        "\n" +
        "@Key1(\"value1\")\n" +
        "@Key2(\"value2\")\n" +
        "\n" +
        "*/\n" +
        "\n" +
        "This is the text that we need to skip. Only wanted to read the above commented section.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "//END_OF_FILE";

AnnotationLexer lexer = new AnnotationLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input));
AnnotationParser parser = new AnnotationParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.parse();
```

which will produce the following output:

```
ID=@Key1, VALUE=("value1")
ID=@Key2, VALUE=("value2")
```

Comment: Thank you Bart, I tried to run the above code but facing an issue while compiling the java files:- AnnotationParserLexer.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                case 0: _mode = INSIDE; break;
                                ^
  symbol:   variable INSIDE
  location: class AnnotationParserLexer
1 error When i googled the problem, I came across this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874689/import-antlr4-lexer-grammar-which-uses-different-modes

Comment: From the name of your generated lexer, `AnnotationParserLexer `, I think you've put all the rules in one file, which you shouldn't. I specifically mentioned in my answer that you needed to define a separate lexer- and parser-grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much Bart, you're my hero. :-)

Comment: Bart, If we have value as (type="String", classifier="Hello") in Input file. Is there any way in ANTLR4 we can also make it as key value pair like ID=type, VALUE=("String") and ID=classifier, VALUE="Hello". Please help.